# Match .h, .m, .mm files but NOT .html

Tags: bash

I want to do some processing on just the source files of type `.h, .m, .mm`. I do NOT want to include the `.html` files.

The following misses the .mm files as I'm only matching `.h` or `.m` and not trying to catch longer extensions.

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.[hm]"
```

This only catches the .mm files, as the ? operator always matches a character. I'd like it to be an optional zero or one match like in regex.

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.[hm]?"
```

But if I use * instead, it matches 0 or multiple characters. This returns everything, but also has the .html files that I don't want.

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.[hm]*"
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: If you prefer to use `regex` patterns, `find` has that capability. Try `find . -regex ".*\.\(h\|m\|mm\)"`.

Comment: @alvits This is exactly what I was looking for, but I can't seem to make your example work. As soon as I put in the | condition it breaks. I have also tried the following simpler regex that uses the ? as an option zero or one match without luck either. `find . -type f -regex ".*\.[hm]m?"`

Comment: The correct regex for that would be `find . -regex ".*\.\([hm]\|mm\)"`.

Comment: Still no luck. If I drop the second part of the search it works (finds .h and .m files) `find . -regex ".*\.\([hm]\)"` but if I do your command above it returns nothing.

Comment: Can you tell me what OS you are running and the version of find? I'm running redhat 6.6 and findutils 4.4.2.

Comment: If you are running `OSX` you should use `-E` to tell `find` the expression is an extended expression. Use this on OSX `find -E . -regex ".*\.([hm]|mm)"`.

Comment: I'm on Mac OSX 10.11.4. That was the problem. I needed the -E option. I ended up with `find -E . -type f -regex ".*\.[hm]m?"` IMO this is the best solution. If this was an answer not just a comment it would be my preferred answer. I don't plan to use anything but modern regex with find in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were running **OS X**. There is `-E` switch that you can use to tell `find` that the regular expression is an extended expression.

> Interpret regular expressions followed by -regex and -iregex primaries as extended (modern) regular expressions rather than basic regular expressions (BRE's).  The re_format(7) manual page fully describes both formats.

Your command should now work:

```
find -E . -type f -regex ".*\.([hm]|mm)"
```

Comment: I really like this ability to use a full regex instead of the other options on `find`. Thanks for pointing this out - I'll be using it exclusively in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine conditions:

```
find -type f -and \( -name '*.h' -or -name '*.m' -or -name '*.mm' \)
```

Or:

```
find ./ -type f -and -name '*.[hm]*' -and -not  -name '*.html'
```

Comment: Although the OP didn't say what other files may exist or may not even be aware that other files may exist than the 3 mentioned, your second solution will find other files that may end in `.mpg`, `,mpa`, `.mpeg` and a lot more.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I ended up with `find ./ -type f -and \( -name '*.[hm]' -or -name '*.mm' \)`

Comment: Agreed. I need the first option here, as I need to explicitly match exactly the .h, .m .mm, and nothing else.

Comment: @alvits, you're completely right, just wanted to show some other possibilities.

Comment: Although these options to find work, I find it much easier to use the -E flag and -regex as described in the comments under the question. I'd rather just use regex than the above syntax.